# If all Rows have Checkmark, then Enable a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, and I need to **enable a Navigation Bar Button when all rows have a `Checkmark`**.

Is there a way to do this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(print_Message)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"didSelectRow");

    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [messageAlert show];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You need to update and check your data model in `didSelectRowAtIndexPaths`. And `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs to show (or not) the checkmark based on the data model.

Comment: Right, yeah that is what I was thinking generally, just trying to figure out how to specifically implement

Comment: Is your table going to need to scroll at all though? Will it all fit on screen? If you don't have to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` repeatedly, then you don't have to change your data model as @rmaddy's suggests in order to find out the selected rows.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Always use a data model, even if all rows might fit. The table might need to reload. And things could change over time. Best to set it up correctly from the beginning and avoid getting bit by some unexpected case later on.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I only have three rows in the table, so it all fits on screen.  What would you suggest in that case?

Comment: @rmaddy do you have a link by chance to some other SO question/answer I can peek at to figure out specifically how to implement?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` won't be called multiple times on an index path (for example in the case of scrolling, forced reloading, the view reappearing, etc.), you can do utilize your `UITableView`'s `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to help figure out whether all the cells are selected.

A few changes to your code are necessary though in order to get `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to work.

(1) Add `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;` in your `viewDidLoad`.

(2) In your initial code, you utilize `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` at the end of the method. Instead, use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` such that the checkmarked rows are selected and the checkmark-free rows are not selected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(print_Message)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    // If the number of selected index paths = the number of rows,
    // enable the button
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    if (selectedIndexPaths.count == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: @SRMR Cool, thanks :) And rmaddy's generally right about what he said, but I don't think it's necessary in this simple case since there doesn't seem to be anything you've described that would be forcing a data re-load.

Comment: One quick follow up:  The "Done" button gets enabled when all three have checkmarks, but, when I tap one of the cells to make it not have a checkmark anymore, the "Done" button stays enabled instead of going back to disabled.  Any idea on that?

Comment: @SRMR Add self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; to didDeselectRowAtIndexPath